# An affordable tool for DB modeling

Tags: database-design, architecture

Could you guys recommend some affordable SQL modeling tool which supports SQL Server, PostgreSQL and MySQL? I'm looking into up to $300 per license range. One tool per answer, please!

Thanks!

Comment: Try this tool for SQL Server Physical models.

Info can be found here...

https://www.facebook.com/DataModelerTool/

or here...

https://plus.google.com/108968161662966473138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has a run down of some of the tools available: http://www.databaseanswers.com/modelling_tools.htm.

I tried Dezign by Datanamic, which the site recommended for the individual user.  It was pretty easy to use and has lots of features. It supports about 20 different databases to various degrees.

It has a free trial and the license is $245 for the Standard edition (not $139 as listed on the site).  I ended up not buying it because I don't have any budget for tools but I would have if I did.  If you need multiple licenses, the 5 and 10 packs offer a significant discount over the single-license fee.

Comment: Thanks, Carlos! I picked up Happy Fish from the link list you linked to. I have 28 days more to try it, but I'm really impressed with what I see. And the price EUR 109 is a bargain.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/visio/default.aspx) and SQL Server Database Diagrams,
one tool not yet mentioned is [EA Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html) which can be purchased for under US$200.00

Answer (score 2):

Keep an eye on [SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com), they are now at beta quality: just visual drawing of entity relationship, forward-engineering into SQL statements, versioning and simple sharing of your schema to others. And they seem to offer free accounts. For MySQL and PG only though.

Guess web-based database modeling is about to take off soon? They are SaaS vendor.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the most comprehensive list on database modeling / design tool would be from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools).

Answer (score 1):

ERwin has always been my favorite data modeling tool.

Comment: ERWin is well outside the quoted budget of $300

Answer (score 0):

Some people I've worked with have had good things to say about [TOAD](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/Overview.htm) - it works with Mysql, though not PostgreSQL.  It is a free download and includes [graphical modeling](http://www.toadsoft.com/toaddm/toad_data_modeler.htm) support.

Answer (score 0):

**Sybase PowerDesigner** is best and most universal database tool i ever saw, but i cant get information about pricing, because "Your country is not currently supported for purchasing online.".

It supports more than 50 databases, including MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL and a lot more. Im not sure about PostgreSQL, but it should be supported.

More information here: http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner